# Asset File Not Updating Via API

Tags: express, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

I cant update assets with 2023-04 version REST Admin Assets API PUT Request. The API can find assets with theme ID and key, but cant update.

@shopify/shopify-api version: 2023-04
Node version: v18.14.2
Operating system: Windows

```
app.get("/api/single_a", verifyRequest, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sessionId = await shopify.session.getCurrentId({
      rawRequest: req,
      rawResponse: res,
    });
    const session = await sessionHandler.loadSession(sessionId);
   
    const client = new shopify.clients.Rest({session});
    const response = await client.get({
      path: 'themes/id/assets',
      query:{
        asset:{
          key: "assets/animations.js"
        }
      }
    });
   
    console.log("value", response.body.asset.value )
    response.body.asset.value = "<p>Heloo world </p>"
    console.log("value changed", response.body.asset.value )
     
    await client.put({
      path: `themes/id/assets`,
      data: response.body.asset
     
    });
     
    console.log("Layout of theme liquid", response);
   
    res.status(200).json({ response }); // Assuming you want to send themes as JSON
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while fetching all Single Asset", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred while fetching Single Asset" });
  }
});
```

The query return this response logs:

```
Error: Received an error response (404 Not Found) from Shopify:
"Not Found"
 If you report this error, please include this id: 7bfa3dfe-cda0-46cf-a522-ee4a1410b549
```

Please fix this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know, Shopify discontinued allowing Apps to use the API to write Assets. If you check your deprecation notices, you'll see that has been the thing for a year now. Perhaps you updated your API version from an old one that tolerated Asset API writes to the newer standard that does not?

Something to check anyway.